# How to retrieve cell value with same result as displayed in Excel?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, rounding

I have the following code:

```
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create( file );
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet( "Sheet1" );
FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter( true );

int rowNum = 0;
int colNum = 0;
Row row = sheet.getRow( rowNum );
Cell cell = row.getCell( colNum );

double rawCellValue = cell.getNumericCellValue();
System.out.println( "raw value: " + rawCellValue );

String cellValue = formatter.formatCellValue( cell, evaluator );
System.out.println( "formatted: " + cellValue );
```

This produces the output:

```
raw value: 1713.6
formatted: $1,713
```

When I open the file in Excel Professional 2010, the value displays as $1,714

[image: Excel screenshot]

Any ideas why POI produces a different value than Excel? Is there a way to configure POI so that it returns the same value (i.e. obeys the same rounding algorithm as Excel)?

I'm using POI 3.12 with a xls (Excel 97-2013) file.

**EDIT:** The java format for this cell is `$#,##0` (internal to POI). Here's what Excel shows:

[image: Excel's cell format dialog]

**EDIT 2:** Perhaps this is a problem with Java, not POI. The following code:

```
double number = 1713.6;
System.out.println( "double   : " + number );

DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#0");

format.setRoundingMode( RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN );
System.out.println( "HALF_DOWN: " + format.format( number ) );

format.setRoundingMode( RoundingMode.HALF_UP );
System.out.println( "HALF_UP  : " + format.format( number ) );
```

Produces the result:

```
double   : 1713.6
HALF_DOWN: 1714
HALF_UP  : 1713
```

Why would HALF_DOWN round *up* but HALF_UP round *down*?

Comment: Related: [Matching Excel's floating point in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28537614/matching-excels-floating-point-in-java)

Comment: The format should not be the problem. It's the default currency format in both Excel and POI. I've tried this and can't reproduce. `formatter.formatCellValue( cell, evaluator )` is `$1,714` for me if `cell.getNumericCellValue()`is `1713.6`. What is the Excel cell content in `A1`? A Formula? Which?

Comment: No formula. The value is exactly 1713.6 in Excel

Comment: Posted last edit as a separate followup [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30650834/539048)

Answer (score 2):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30651564/539048). Looks like the problem is related to a [rounding bug](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8039915) in certain version of java 8. This was fixed with 8u40 ([Release Notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/2col/8u40-bugfixes-2423829.html)).