# Why does HALF_UP sometimes round down with double?

Tags: java, rounding

The following code:

```
double doubleValue = 1713.6;
float floatValue = 1713.6f;
String fs = "%-9s : %-7s %-7s\n";
System.out.printf( fs, "", "double", "float" );

DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#0");
System.out.printf( fs, "toString", String.valueOf( doubleValue ), String.valueOf( floatValue ) );

format.setRoundingMode( RoundingMode.DOWN );
System.out.printf( fs, "DOWN", format.format( doubleValue ), format.format( floatValue ) );

format.setRoundingMode( RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN );
System.out.printf( fs, "HALF_DOWN", format.format( doubleValue ), format.format( floatValue ) );

format.setRoundingMode( RoundingMode.HALF_UP );
System.out.printf( fs, "HALF_UP", format.format( doubleValue ), format.format( floatValue ) );

format.setRoundingMode( RoundingMode.UP );
System.out.printf( fs, "UP", format.format( doubleValue ), format.format( floatValue ) );
```

Produces the result ([live code](https://ideone.com/ZohDaA)):

```
          : double  float  
toString  : 1713.6  1713.6 
DOWN      : 1713    1713   
HALF_DOWN : 1714    1714   
HALF_UP   : 1713    1714   <--- notice this line
UP        : 1714    1714
```

I know that certain numbers cannot be represented exactly as floating-point numbers. The actual floating-point representation for 1713.6 is 1713.5999755859375 (see [this page](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html)).

But **why does HALF_UP round *down* in this case?**

Using Java 1.8u25

Comment: Which version of Java is that and on which platform? It prints 1714 on my machine, both in Java 1.7 and Java 1.8.

Comment: Prints 1713 on JDK 1.8b25, 64bit, Linux.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There was a bug in Java 8 regarding the NumberFormat and RoundingMod HALF_UP see [8039915](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8039915). This was fixed with 8u40 ([Release Notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/2col/8u40-bugfixes-2423829.html)).

Answer (score 1):

Ideone is using sun-jdk-8u25 where this buggy behavior is appearing.

On Java 1.7, I'm getting HALF_UP   : 1714    1714 which is right.

enum RoundingMode - Specifies a rounding behavior for numerical operations capable of discarding precision.

[See Oracle javadoc: Result of rounding input to one digit with the given rounding mode[Rounding Mode Table]](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html)

Comment: Rounding table is useful to understand outcome of RoundingMode.x operation.