# How can 0.2 + 0.1 be equal to 0.3 in Excel?

Tags: excel, floating-point

I understand perfectly why 0.1 + 0.2 is not equal to 0.3 due to the floating point. In most of programming languages, `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3` is `False`.

But in Excel `if(0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3; 1; 0)` gives 1

Comment: Possibly useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel

Comment: @BigBen: I see that Excel also uses the IEEE 754 floating point as other languages, which indeed causes the comparison to be false

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40293983/270986

Answer (score 8):

The reason this happens in Excel is because Excel only keeps track of 15 digits of precision.  Floating point math for 0.2 + 0.1 results in `0.30000000000000004`, and that 4 way out there is the 17th digit.  That means Excel just truncates everything after the 15th 0 and is left with `0.300000000000000` which = `0.3`

See here for more info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel

Comment: I think it's a bit more complicated than this in practice; there's some hidden magic going on. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/53337274,  https://stackoverflow.com/q/40293983,  https://stackoverflow.com/q/36452194

Comment: You're saying that when Excel compare `0.30000000000000004` to `0.3`, it's actually comparing two strings? Because I don't know how it keeps track of only 15 digits.